# Curve fitting in Python with Scipy

Tags: python, data-modeling, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

Just would like to address that I am a very beginner programmer with python. Most of my knowledge is what I use/learned for data analysis/plotting for my physics labs.

I basically gathered data of capacitance as a function of temperature, and I am supposed to fit the data I plotted with a function to find its optimal parameters.

Note that I put in random numbers for my initial values, then ran the code. My `POpt` function gave me new optimal parameters for which I replaced with my initial random numbers

```
fig, plot = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,40))

def cap(T, Cmax, K, TC, gamma): #this is the function I am fitting to my data
    return Cmax/(1+K*(T-TC)**gamma)
CmaxInit = 5.16061523 #these are the optimal parameters it gave me
KInit = 3.87292298e-05
TCInit = 3.00020150e+01
gammaInit =  2.74812849
fmodel = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
plt.plot(fmodel, cap(fmodel, CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, gammaInit), linewidth=8, label='Fitted model')

plot.errorbar(temperature, capacitance, linewidth=8, label='Data Points') #this is my data of temperature vs capacitance

pOpt, pCov = curve_fit(cap, temperature, capacitance, p0=[CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, gammaInit], absolute_sigma=True) #this is what I use to curve-fit/get my optimal parameters
print("[CmaxOpt KOpt TCOpt gammaOpt] =", pOpt)
print()
print("pCov =") #This is a co-variant matrix function that calculates my error values
print(pCov)

plt.xticks(fontsize=60)
plt.yticks(fontsize=60)
plt.grid()
plt.legend(fontsize=80)
plt.show()
```

However when plotting my fitted model, it gives me:

Capacitance as a function of Temperature

[image]

The `POpt` function did somewhat fit the general look, but it is clearly way off. I do not understand why, but my guess would be of the number of parameters I am trying to optimize.

Edit: Changing the initial parameters to

```
CmaxInit = 6 
KInit = 0.01
TCInit = 50
gammaInit =  2
```

produced a more accurate fit of [image: this]

But now it produced an error when calculating the optimal parameters.

```
[CmaxOpt KOpt TCOpt gammaOpt] = [nan nan nan nan]
```

Edit 2: After chopping my data, I am now trying to fit [image: this]

However I am still getting

```
[CmaxOpt KOpt TCOpt gammaOpt] = [nan nan nan nan]
```

An exponential function would seem to fit this better than the equation I am supposed to model. Maybe that's why I am not getting optimal parameters?

Comment: looks like your curve fitting found a local optimal solution for your parameters and cant escape it. Try giving the algorithm better start values for your parameters. See docs on how to do that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: I'm thinking of what causes this restriction. I have done this curve fit before, although with exponential decays so I guess the program was able to easily optimize it. So are you suggesting using trial and error initial values, and then optimizing it? Because that would seem like a lot of plug and chug.

Comment: The optimization landscape can look completely different if you fit a different kind of function and thus sometime those methods may fail. Your data looks like your fit parameters should be close to:  `CmaxInit = 6; KInit =0.01; gamma=2;TCInit = 50` Try those as starting points rather then using random ones and report the result pls. Your gamma parameter seems to bee quite off

Comment: It did seem to help actually, but now it is unable to optimize my values. I made an edit above.

Comment: I found this to be an interesting problem, and extracted data from your plot for analysis. I have been working on it for a few hours now using scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to give initial parameter estimates for different ranges of potential initial parameter values. While other peak equations fit the data fairly well - it does show a peak - I had no success in fitting this data set to the given equation. I suggest carefully verifying the form of the equation is both syntactically correct and matches the known physics of the experiment.

Comment: This is the equation that was given on my lab-script. I actually noticed now that they do say to plot for T>TC (TC is the "Curie Temperature" if you want to know), but that condition shouldn't change the shape of my graph, just where I start plotting it.

Comment: Is it possible that this specific equation is only *valid* for temperatures greater than TC, given that instruction?

Comment: That might make sense. My professor did mention something about chopping our data. I will chop at around 50 degrees and try fitting that, as that seems to be our peak capacitance and our TC value. I'm also not sure why my fitting function doesn't produce optimal parameters anymore; it was working fine at first.

Comment: Your question is not a matplotlib question, it's a scipy.optimize question. It would be obvious with a proper [mcve]. Please [edit] and try to add what is missing and remove what is not crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some numerical problems with the fitting function:

- it seems to be too hard for the algorithm to have an exponent (gamma)
  as a fitting parameter. This seems also to be true for something as
  `exp(gamma)`
- I replaced the fitting function by
  `Cmax*np.exp(-K*(T-TC)**2) + c`. With that it dependes on the x-range
  (data window) how good the fit is.
- for numerical reasons it might be better to have an intercept `c`.
- it is often a good idea to bring the data by transformation to "an easy region" of the the fitting function, so that the peak is around zero and the x-range is around [-5..+5]. After fitting you transform the results back to the original data range.
- fitting the log(data) instaed of (data) can help sometimes too.

...

```
def cap(T, Cmax, K, TC, gamma):         
    return Cmax/(1+K*(T-TC)**gamma)

def func_1(T, Cmax, K, TC, c):
    return Cmax*np.exp(-K*(T-TC)**2) + c

#--- generate data --------------------
CmaxInit =  5.0         # 5.16061523      
KInit =     3.0e-3      # 3.87292298e-05
TCInit =    30.0         # 3.00020150e+01
gammaInit = 2.0         # 2.74812849
cInit =     0.0         # intercept

fmodel = np.linspace(20, 50, 280)
x0 = fmodel.copy()

y0 = cap   (x0, CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, gammaInit)
y1 = func_1(x0, CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, cInit)
y_noise = 0.05 * np.random.normal(size=x0.size)
Y0 = y0 + y_noise
Y1 = y1 + y_noise

#--- fit the data by a function ------------
pOpt, pCov = curve_fit(func_1, x0, Y0,  p0=[CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, cInit], absolute_sigma=True)
Yfit = func_1(x0, *pOpt)

#--- print the results ---------------------------
print("CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, c", CmaxInit, KInit, TCInit, c)
print("[CmaxOpt KOpt TCOpt cOpt] =", pOpt); print()
print("pCov ="); print(pCov)

#---- graphics --------------------------------------------
fig, plot = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.plot(x0, Y0, linewidth=2, label='simulated data with CAP')
plt.plot(x0, Y1, ls=':', lw=1,label='simulated data with EXP')
plt.plot(x0, Yfit,  label='Yfit: Cmax=%5.3f, K=%5.3f, TC=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(pOpt))
plt.legend(); plt.savefig('pic3.jpg'); plt.show()
```

..
[image]

[image]

Comment: I realized that I had to chop my data so my function is modeled starting from `T>TC` (3rd figure), and this error is gone now. I am confused on why I get errors now when trying to obtain optimal parameters. It was working fine before, now for any initial values that I input, I get `nan` for all of them. Would it be worth mentioning that there is a subtlety in my data. It is hard to notice because this data collection ran for about 30 minutes, but there are choppy points where the temperature stabilized for about 30 seconds (we made it do that).

Comment: I enhanced my answer

Comment: I will talk to my professor tomorrow as this should have been a simple fitting exercise, but I am understanding that given the amount of parameters, it will have some difficulty fitting. Thank you.